# Rename a bunch of files and adding an index counter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have to rename a bunch of files. They're all in the same folder. My idea was to do this by a batch script, but the problem is, that I have to "split" the original filename and give it an indexing number.

For example:

```
Original Filename: XYZ SomeDocument.docx
New Filename: XYZ 01 SomeDocument.docx
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can do this?

Comment: do all filenames have the same syntax "text-space-text" without any additional spaces? Or is the first part (XYZ) of fixed length  ("xxx sometext")?

Comment: Yes, all files have the same syntax. And also the XYZ is the same at each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set index=100
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
   set /A index+=1
   ren "%%a %%b" "%%a !index:~-2! %%b"
)
```

Comment: @user1619655 Note that this won't work correctly when you have more than 99 files to rename in that folder. It also doesn't handle name conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Python](http://python.org/download/) for tasks like this :)

Eg:

```
import os

DIR = r'C:\foo'

index = 1
for file_name in os.listdir(DIR):
    old_path = os.path.join(DIR, file_name)
    split = file_name.split("XYZ")
    new_file_name = "XYZ %s %s" % (index, split[1].strip())
    new_path = os.path.join(DIR, new_file_name)
    os.rename(old_path, new_path)
    index += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm sorry, I'm not allowed to use Python for this (It's a task at work ;) ). So It has to be a batch or VB Script.